# Unity app on Android is not shown as installed package

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a project where use a custom Android launcher (android 4.2.2). The launcher shows games which are made in Adobe Air. Now we want to expand the list of games with Unity games.

To show the games we use the PackageManager and filter on name e.g.: air.Bimii. Namespace of both technologies are kept the same: air.BimiiMath, air.BimiiABC and so on.

The problem is that the games made in Unity are not listed when using:

```
private ArrayList<LocalAppDetail> initAppList(){
    ArrayList<LocalAppDetail> res = new ArrayList<LocalAppDetail>();
    PackageManager main_package_manager =  main_activity.getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = main_package_manager.getInstalledPackages(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {

        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((p.versionName == null)) {
            continue;
        }
        //Store Local Appdetail
        LocalAppDetail newInfo = new LocalAppDetail();
        newInfo.name = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(main_package_manager).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(main_package_manager);

        //Parse if the app meets requirements
        if (newInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(MiscData.apk_filter_text)) {
            if(!newInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("launcher")) {
                if(!newInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("rfid")){                       
                    res.add(newInfo);
                }
            }           
        }
    }
    //Store The Collection
    return res;
}
```

but when i try using ADB: adb shell pm list packages -f air this is the result:

`package:/data/app/air.BimiiFarm-1.apk=air.BimiiFarm
package:/data/app/air.BimiiFood-1.apk=air.BimiiFood
package:/data/app/air.nl.mediaheads.klassewinkel-1.apk=air.nl.mediaheads.klassewinkel
package:/system/app/Air.apk=com.adobe.air
package:/mnt/asec/nl.mediaheadsair.bimiiRekenen-1/pkg.apk=nl.mediaheadsair.bimiiRekenen`

So the game is there (last in the list). The name is pkg.apk and the location is different. Do you guys have an idea about how to catch all the games in a list show we can launch them?

Help would be great! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*Update* Sigh, it was an option in Unity Player settings. Install Location should be put on "Force Internal". What a world, what a world.